# scp a folder to a remote system keeping the directory layout

Tags: linux, scp

I have a large directory tree with hundreds of nested sub-folders. I need to copy only 4 folders and their contents to a remote system, but I need to destination folder structure to be kept the same.

E.G.

```
./test/sub1/subsub1/hello.txt
./test/sub1/subsub2/hello2.txt    
./test/sub2/hello3.txt
```

I want to copy ./test/sub1/subsub1/* to a target such as user@system:~/test/sub1/subsub1/* but I do not want to copy subsub2 or sub2.

I have tried using scp as follows:

```
scp -r ./test/sub1/subsub1 me@my-system:~/test/sub1/subsub1
```

The result: scp: /test/sub1/subsub1: No such file or directory

I also tried:

```
scp -r ./test/sub1/subsub1 me@my-system:~/test
```

This works, but dumps all the files into a single directory. The /test/sub1/subsub1 directory structure is not maintained.

How can I copy a folder, whilst maintaining its structure?

Comment: Lazy version: `tar -cf myfile.tar ./test/sub1/subsub1; scp myfile me@mysystem:~; echo 'tar -xf myfile.tar && rm myfile.ta' | ssh me@mysystem`

Comment: Using an archive also has the advantage that data transmission is faster for one big file than for hundreds of small files (if you have hundreds of small files).

Comment: Very true and great one-liner. I gave this a spin and I do generate the tar file, but get a "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal error".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a two-pass solution. First, ensure the target directory exists on the remote host:

```
ssh me@my-system 'mkdir -p ~/test/sub1/subsub1'
```

Then, you can copy your files. I recommend using `rsync` instead of `scp`, since it's designed for syncing directories. Example usage:

```
rsync -r -e ssh ./test/sub1/subsub1/ me@my-system:~/test/sub1/subsub1
```

The `-e` flag accepts a remote shell to use to carry out the transfer. **Trailing slashes are very important with `rsync`**, so make sure yours match the example above.

Comment: Thx, almost works but I have a little issue. Copying using the first example you give creates /test/subsub1 on the destination machine. The sub1 between test and subsub1 is missing. Also using rsync, if I specify full path, I get a no such directory error.

Comment: I think if you add a / to the end of the first examples source directory that will solve your last issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Placing the slash takes the contents of /test/sub1/subsub1 and dumps it into /test on the target system, removing /subsub1 also.

Comment: Hey Chris, I updated the answer. Since you're not syncing the entire directory tree, which is the most typical use case of rsync, you must ensure the remote dir exists.

Comment: Hey thanks for the follow up and modification; I have just got in and tried update. Unfortunately I cannot create a deep directory path in one go.  ssh me@mine 'mkdir ~/test' passes. ssh me@mine 'mkdir ~/test/sub1' fails with the message: "mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/me/test/sub1': No such file or directory. I'm getting the opinion now that there is no way to directly create a multi-folder deep directory in a single command? Seems rather silly. Cheers for the help

Comment: Updated again: you need the `-p` option to `mkdir`. That should have been there from the start, that's what I get for not copy/pasting from the terminal!

Comment: Aha I know this will work, though don't have the set up to try it, thx man.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately rsync does not have the same security as rsync and does not work everywhere. Will check somewhere else

Answer (score 15):

Use the `-R (--relative)` option to rsync to preserve the directory structure. Take a look at:

https://serverfault.com/questions/39522/how-to-keep-the-full-path-with-rsync

Here's an example:

```
[localbox] tree test
test
└── sub1
    └── subsub1
        ├── a
        ├── b
        ├── c
        ├── d
        ├── e
        └── f


 [localbox] rsync -avR test/sub1/subsub1 me@my-system:dest_path
 sending incremental file list
 created directory dest_path
 test/
 test/sub1/
 test/sub1/subsub1/
 test/sub1/subsub1/a
 test/sub1/subsub1/b
 test/sub1/subsub1/c
 test/sub1/subsub1/d
 test/sub1/subsub1/e
 test/sub1/subsub1/f

 sent 406 bytes  received 185 bytes  394.00 bytes/sec
 total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

 [localbox] ssh me@my-system
 [my-system] tree dest_path
 dest_path
 `-- test
    `-- sub1
        `-- subsub1
            |-- a
            |-- b
            |-- c
            |-- d
            |-- e
            `-- f

  3 directories, 6 files
```

Below is cut from the rsync man page:

> **-R, --relative**
>
> Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on the command line are sent to the server rather than just
>   the last parts of the filenames. This is particularly useful when you
>   want to send several different directories at the same time. For
>   example, if you used this command:

```
     rsync -av /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
```

> ... this would create a file named baz.c in /tmp/ on the remote machine. If instead you used

```
     rsync -avR /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
```

> then a file named /tmp/foo/bar/baz.c would be created on the remote machine, preserving its full path.  These extra path
>   elements are called "implied directories" (i.e. the "foo" and the
>   "foo/bar" directories in the above example).