# Copy tree structure including single file in leaf

Tags: bash

After having run several simulations on a cluster, I would like to copy the results back to my local machine. The results are organised is as follows:

```
foo1
   |bar1
       |run1
           |file1.txt
           |file2.txt
           |results.txt
       |run2
           |file1.txt
           |file2.txt
           |results.txt
   |bar2
       |run1
           |file1.txt
           |file2.txt
           |results.txt
       |run2
           |file1.txt
           |file2.txt
           |results.txt
foo2
... (etc.)
```

Each `run*` folder contains several files, needed to run the simulation, but I am only interested in copying the results, say `results.txt` back to my local machine while maintaining the rest of the tree structure (the directories basically specifies the parameters for the simulation).

How can I now copy only the `results.txt` files from remote to local, while maintaining the tree structure of the directories? Such that I on local end up with

```
foo1
   |bar1
       |run1
           |results.txt
       |run2
           |results.txt
   |bar2
       |run1
           |results.txt
       |run2
           |results.txt
foo2
... (etc.)
```

Comment: Your question is how to copy from remote to local? or how to copy only those files from the remote?

Comment: @Inian, How to copy only the `results.txt` files from remote to local, while maintaining the tree structure of the directories. I have also included a sketch of the wanted outcome in the question

Comment: I think the answer is either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393908/scp-a-folder-to-a-remote-system-keeping-the-directory-layout) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650164/bash-copy-named-files-recursively-preserving-folder-structure)

Comment: @oliv, Not completely. The first link want to exclude other folders, I do not. The second link want to copy everything keeping the tree structure, whereas I am only interested in copying a single file. On the other hand I admit that the solutions are very similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With find and tar:

```
find -name result.txt | tar cvfz results.tgz -T -
```

then you need to copy the tar and untar it:

```
tar xvfz results.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two stages:

```
find . -type f -name results.txt | xargs tar -f results.tar
```

This finds all of the files (`-type f`) named results.txt and then pipes the results into a tarball.

The second stage would be to `scp` back from the cluster to your local machine.